# Trying to record the position of reader in an array

Tags: c#, stream, streamreader

This program displays chunks of text to help the user memorize. Each time the user presses a button another chunk of text is displayed.
I'm trying to record the positions of the punctuation marks. When the user presses a 'less text' button a chunk of text is removed... i.e..

User presses retrieve text 3 times

A label displays....I went, to the house, it was good.

user presses 'less text' once;

The label displays.....I went, to the house,

My problem is with the 'less text' button. I would like that button to be able to check the reader positions that have been stored in an array, and then display the text up till the second last punctuation mark recorded in the array. I feel that the way I'm using BaseStream.Position is not correct. I can't seem to find clarity on how to record the position of a reader object.  thank you.

public partial class frmMainWindow : Form
    {
        public frmMainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

```
    // Creates an object that we can append values to and create a string
    StringBuilder textToMemorize = new StringBuilder();

    // Reads in text from a file. This is the text that the user will memorize
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Jason\Desktop\MemorizerTestApplication\WindowsFormsApplication1\bin\Debug\Test Document.txt");


    // The point where the character is beig read by the input stream
    int readPoint;

    // And Array to contain all the places where the a puctuation mark has already stopped the displaying of more text
    long[] stopPoint = new long[20];

    // Integer to move the element in the stop point array
    int p = 0;

    // The return value for the skipPunctuation method
    bool doAppend;

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the Click event of the retrieve text button
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool flag = true;

        // Collects each character from the text file and checks for punctuation    
        while((readPoint = reader.Read()) > 0 && flag == true)
        {
            // Casts the current letter into a character
            char c = (char)readPoint;

            // Checks for punctuation
            if (c == ',' || c == ';' || c == '.')
            {
                    // Stores the readPoint where there is a punctuation mark
                    stopPoint[p] = reader.BaseStream.Position;

                    textToMemorize.Append((char)c);
                    p++;
                    flag = false;
            }

            else
            {
                // Appends the character to the text
                textToMemorize.Append((char)c);
            }
        }
        // Displays text from the string building to the label
        lblTextToLearn.Text = textToMemorize.ToString();

     }

            private void btnLessText_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Clear the label
        lblTextToLearn.Text = string.Empty;

        //Clears the String Builder object
        textToMemorize.Clear();

        // Sets the internal stream back to zero
        reader.DiscardBufferedData();

        // Sets the stream back to zero
        reader.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        bool stopLoop = true;

        // Loop the reader
        while ((readPoint = reader.Read()) > 0 && stopLoop == true)
        {

            // Cast the read point to a char
           char d = (char)readPoint;

            // Append the char to the string builder objecy
            textToMemorize.Append(d);

            // Display the string to the label
            lblTextToLearn.Text = textToMemorize.ToString();

            // CHeck the second last element of the array to know how many char's to print to the screen
            if (reader.BaseStream.Position == stopPoint[p-1])
            {
                stopLoop = false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

with the stream reader position, this is a heavily task

here some other way to do this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

public partial class test
{
    // temp string
    String temp = string.Empty;

    // array of readed text
    char[] chars;

    // helper variable
    int found = 0;

    // compare list
    List<String> compare = new List<string>() { ",", ";", "." };

    // Stream Reader
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("file.txt");

    public string increaseText()
    {
        // Read next line if end of this line
        if (chars == null || (found > 0 && temp.Length >= chars.Length))
        {
            // read whole line
            chars = reader.ReadLine().ToCharArray();
        }

        // check every char
        for (int i = found; i < chars.Length; i++)
        {
            temp += chars[i].ToString();

            // if stop sign found, exit and return our string
            if (compare.Contains(chars[i].ToString()))
            {
                found = i + 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        return temp;
    }

    public string decreaseText()
    {
        // get all chars
        char[] compChars = temp.ToCharArray();

        // check every char
        for (int i = temp.Length-1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            // if stop sign found, decrease text
            if (compare.Contains(compChars[i-1].ToString()))
            {
                found = i;
                temp = temp.Substring(0, i);
                break;
            }
        }
        return temp;
    }
}
```

read every line of code works fine too, hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically reader.BaseStream.Position doesn't contain what you think.

From the documentation:
    [The Position property does not keep track of the number of bytes from the stream that have been consumed, skipped, or both.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.IO.Stream.Position);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.2);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true)

If you want to use a stream for this you will have to count the consumed characters yourself.